# Xamarin Navigation with Modal page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to open modal window in my app, to do it we use method like this:

```
 public async Task OpenModal<T>(object parameter = null)
     where T : BaseViewModel
 {
     var modal = _pageService.CreatePageFor<T>(parameter);
     await _navigation.PushModalAsync(modal, false);
 }
```

The call is done in another viewmodel, which shows modal page. After everything is done, I have to go to the root page. I call

```
await _navigation.PopToRootAsync(false);
```

and after that

```
await _navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

The thing is that `PopToRootAsync` never completes and the call await for ever for iOS (not for Android). If I change order of `PopToRootAsync` and `PopModalAsync`, then I have flashing, which is not acceptable in our case.

I read this:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22156/poptorootasync-with-modal

but still cannot find the solution, any suggestions?

Comment: Is it also flashing when you set the animation argument to true?

Comment: Yes, the same flashing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure a smooth transition animation my suggestion would be to manually remove all pages from the navigation stack but the root and then proceed to pop your modal. Here's some example code to give you an idea of what you might have to add to your navigation service implementation.

```
var navigationStack = MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
var rootPage = navigationStack.FirstOrDefault();

for (int i = navigationStack.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var page = navigationStack[i];
    if (page.GetType() == rootPage.GetType())
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Navigation.RemovePage(page);
    }
}

Navigation.PopModalAsync(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolutelayout!

```
<AbsoluteLayout  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="className">
    <!-- Transparent Background -->
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 BackgroundColor="Gray"
                 Opacity="0.5"
                 >       
    </StackLayout>
    <!-- Content -->
    <ContentView x:Name="Overlay"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 Padding="10, 0">
    <Label Text="myLabel">
        <!-- Overlay -->
    </ContentView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```